# yiibooster TbSelect2 throws 'uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2' when trying to open in modal

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

I am trying to open a form containing yiibooster TbSelect2 in a modal dialog using AJAX call and renderPartial(). It throws this error:

uncaught exception: query function not defined for Select2 Patient_state

It only happens if I try to populate the modal with the AJAX call. Works fine if I just load a page with the form. Please help!

Here is the code:
Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Patient;
    $this->_createUpdate($model);
}

private function _createUpdate($model)
{
    if (isset($_POST['Patient'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Patient'];
        if ($model->save()) {
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
                echo CJSON::encode($model->attributes);
                Yii::app()->end();
            } else {
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }
        }
    }

    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
        $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model' => $model), false, true);
    } else {
        $this->render('update', array('model' => $model));
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<?php
/* @var $this PatientController */
/* @var $model Patient */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
    Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.min.js'] = false;
}
?>

<div class="form" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'patient-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'first_name', array('size' => 37,'maxlength' => 100)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'last_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'last_name', array('size' => 37,'maxlength' => 100)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'last_name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'addr1'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'addr1', array('size' => 37,'maxlength' => 256)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'addr1'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'city'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'city', array('size' => 37,'maxlength' => 100)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'city'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="inline">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state'); ?>
        <?php
        $this->widget(
            'booster.widgets.TbSelect2',
            array(
                'model'      =>  $model,
                'attribute'  =>  'state',
                'data'       =>  array('AL' => 'Alaska', 'CA' => 'California'),
                    'value'      =>  $model->state,
                'options'    =>  array(
                    'placeholder'  =>  'Select',
                )
            )
        );
        ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'state'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="inline" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'postal_code'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'postal_code', array('size' => 10,'maxlength' => 10)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'postal_code'); ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'dob'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'dob', array('id'  =>  'dob-input')); ?>
    <div id="dob-hints" class="hint">MM/DD/YYYY
    </div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'dob'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php
    if ($model->isNewRecord) {
        $buttonLabel =  'Create';
        $url = $this->createUrl('create');
    } else {
        $buttonLabel =  'Save';
        $url = $this->createUrl('update', array("id" => $model->id));
    }
    ?>
    <?php $this->widget(
        'booster.widgets.TbButton',
        array(
            'label' => $buttonLabel,
            'context' => 'primary',
            'buttonType' => 'link',
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'id' => 'submit-button',
                'onClick' => 'submit();')
        )
    );
    ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the lines removing jquery from the Script Map? Or specifically including select2 on ajax load, with Booster::getBooster()->registerPackage('select2'); ?

Comment: I have tried the first, but not the second. For now I have a workaround of creating CHtml::dropDownList and then converting it to select2 :
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#state-select').select2(
        {
            placeholder: "Select a state",
            allowClear: true
        }
    );
});